# Laravel - Validación before_or_equal:date desde datetime-local

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy manejando 4 fechas;

- 2 de ellas son input date (fecha inicio y fecha fin).
- Las otras 2 son input datetime-local (fecha inicio examen y fecha fin
  examen)

Los input datetime-local deben estar dentro del rango de los input date.

Entiendo que cuando se le dice a Laravel una comparación de date, por defecto deja las horas como 00:00, quisiera saber como dejarlo por defecto en 23:59 para poder hacer lo siguiente:

```
'fechaFinExamen' => 'before_or_equal:fechaFin'
```

Y que la fechaFin tenga las horas como 23:59 para que la validación la haga de manera correcta.

Para entrar mas en contexto para los que no entiendan lo que quiero validar:

- Digamos que al fechaFin (input date) coloco 25/03/2021
- Y si al fechaFinExamen (input datetime-local) coloco 25/03/2021 16:30

Debería dejar guardar los datos, pero no es así, porque me indica que "fechaFinExamen" es mayor que "fechaFin".

Un saludo y de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que tu principal problema es que las fechas que envías, efectivamente no son iguales, es decir, no es lo mismo una fecha DATE a una DATETIME, entonces, cuando las validas, ocurre el error

Comment: Porque simplemente la `fechaFin` no se guarda con horas "23:59"? Es mas, deberia ser un `datetime` ese valor

Comment: Si lo tengo presente todo eso, usé date en lugar de datetime para ahorrar espacio en la base de datos, ya que el date usa 3 bytes mientras que datetime usa 8, además de que algunos registros no me interesa la hora, sino la fecha. ¿No tendrán una solución para que deje los datos tal cual como están? Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una nueva fecha con `Carbon` para comparar a partir de tu `fechaFin`

```
$fechaFin2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',  $fechaFin.' 23:59:59');
```

De esa forma estas utilizando tu variable tipo `date` para crear una nueva utilizando cualquier hora, en este caso 23:59:59